# Xcode text rendering bug?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Sometimes in Xcode, when I am towards the end of a file, the editor starts scrambling the lines. I have a video of it below. You can see when I close the bracket the text goes back to normal:

http://vimeo.com/18678901

Any idea if there are ways around this? Restarting Xcode doesn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a bug. Please file that on [bugreporter.apple.com](http://bugreporter.apple.com) along with the version of Xcode you were using at the time. If it's reproducible and you can attach the project/file to the bug, please do. For extra credit, post the bug # here so I can follow up on it, thanks.

P.S. Please check the Console for silent exceptions from Xcode. My colleague reminded me to ask you about this.

Comment: Done. ID# 8854827. At the time of the errors there are no messages in the console, but there was an error around the time of launching xcode: "1/12/11 2:19:33 PM Xcode[39579] Unable to find either a loadable database or a Nodes.xml configuration file"